Let $\omega =\rho d\theta$ be a volue form of the circle $S^1$. Who are the diffeomorphisms of the circle that let $\omega$ invariant?
Consider the parametrization $\phi:]0,2\pi[\to S^1$ given by $\phi(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$. So the Lebesgue measure is given in local coordinates by the form $d\theta_z(\partial_z)=1$. I know that the diffeomorphisms of the circle that preserve Lebesgue are the rigid rotations and the rigid reflections. But whe I analyse it via pullbacks of the diffeos (also in local coordinates), what I get is
$$f^*d\theta=d\theta$$
iff
$$f'(x)d\theta=d\theta$$
Thus, $f'(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x+c$, which is a rigid translation. A reflection would invert orientation, so its somehow missing.
I am using this argument to try to understand who would be the diffeos such that for a given $\rho\in C^\infty(S^1)$ (with $\rho>0$) would let $\omega = \rho d\theta$ invariant. What I get is
$$(f^*\omega)_x
(\partial_x)=\omega_{f(x)}
(f_*\partial_x)=\rho(f(x))f'(x)$$
So, $f^*\omega=\omega$ iff
$$\rho(f(x))f'(x)=1.$$
If $R$ is the primitive of $\rho$, then by integrating the equation above we get
$$R(f(x))=x+c.$$
Can I get any further?

Preserving measure and preserving volume form are not the same. Why?

@TedShifrin, does it have something to do with orientation?

Yes, precisely. (I also would not use $x$ as a variable when I'm writing $d\theta$. $\theta$ is your local coordinate.) I agree with your differential equation, but now you really do need to think about what $x$ and primitive mean when you're working on $S^1$. Everything needs to be periodic up on $\Bbb R$.
